# Open source tool to read batch CSV files and output parameter results?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, csv, file-search

I am looking for a tool that could scan batch csv files and ensure that all preset parameters are accurately reflected in the output file. Essentially, scan batch CSV files, ensure the preset parameters stay in place prior to using the CSV files to run a report.

I am **NOT** looking for a tool that just outputs CSV values or a CSV viewer/editor; the tool would read csv files and filter data based on preset parameters.

The tool would be able to search in the CSV file for document types that are intended to have been filtered out. The main reason for the tool is to run validation before the CSV files go to an SFTP.

The tool would be installed on a linux server and scripted out to run, or able to be automated in another environment.

**Additionally, the hope is that the tool could look at dates and determine if a record is outside the expected date range.**

**A bonus** would be some form of automation that would check the csv for preset parameters, and output whether they were missing or not before running a report with a csv file that has no parameters.

Resources I checked so far:

- https://thegeekpage.com/best-free-csv-editor-for-windows-10/
- https://medium.com/@presactlyalicia/filtering-csv-files-outside-of-a-spreadsheet-f60e75d4c054
- https://download.cnet.com/CSVed/3001-2351_4-52868.html
- https://www.moderncsv.com/
- https://www.tadviewer.com/
- https://kothar.net/csview

Comment: @RomeoNinov since when is Excel open source, and since when does it run on Linux? // "The tool would be installed on a linux server": **jcthomas112** might wish to replace the `windows-20` tag by `linux` I guess ;)